# Configurator Scan not picking up views

Tags: python, pyramid

New to Py and Python. I'm trying to get pyramid Configurator scan to find my views, but I seem to be missing something, it's not picking up my "view" `index` here are my files:

app.py

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator

if __name__ == '__main__':

    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.scan()

    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 6543, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

and index.py

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
from pyramid.response import Response

    @view_config(route_name='home')
    def index(request):
        print'Incoming request'
        return Response('<body><h1>Home</h1></body>')
```

Its returning a 404. However, if I remove `config.scan()` and add the view manually it works fine.

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from index import index

if __name__ == '__main__':

    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.add_view(index, route_name='home')
```

Comment: Is your index.py in a sub-folder? If so, in Python you have to add a file named `__init__.py` in the folder (leave it empty), so the folder becomes a package.

Comment: Both files are in the same (root) directory, however I should have mentioned this is running in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Pyramid documentation

> scan(package=None, categories=None, onerror=None, ignore=None, **kw)[source]
>   Scan a Python package and any of its subpackages for objects marked with configuration decoration such as pyramid.view.view_config. Any decorated object found will influence the current configuration state.

The package argument should be a Python package or module object (or a dotted Python name which refers to such a package or module). If package is None, the package of the caller is used. In this case it is looking for decorations in app package or app.py file.

To fix this add

```
config.scan(package='index')
```

or rename `app.py` to `__init__.py`